# IObservableCollection<ViewModel<T>> wrapping ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, design-patterns

In C#/WPF, what is the best way to provide a class which implements `IObservableCollection<ViewModel<T>>` and wraps around `ObservableCollection<T>` from the model?

The model can add/remove T elements to the underlying collection, or the view could add/remove ViewModel elements from the view-model layer.

Is there anything fishy about this from the standpoint of the MVVM pattern? Are there libraries containing this, or a similar class?

Comment: Whats wrong with a class that just contains a property of type `ObservableCollection<MyModel>` or even `ObservableCollection<MyViewModel<MyModel>>`? I've never understood why people always want to write something that inherits from `ObservableCollection`... it's just like a `List`, but with Change Notification. You don't overwrite `List<T>` to make a data class, and you shouldn't overwrite `ObservableCollection<T>` either (unless it's to extend the functionality of the list/collection)

Comment: @Rachel I have a list view and where each item is `ItemModel`, and I need to wrap each of them in `ItemViewModel`. In MVVM pattern, the model should not be directly exposed to the view.

Comment: The "MVVM-Purist" approach is to never expose the model to the View, however quite often it is more practical to do it this way so either method is valid. And even if you want to stick with that design pattern, I still don't see why you want to overwrite `ObservableCollection`. Your ViewModel should instead contain a property of type `ObservableCollection<SomeViewModel>`, and `SomeViewModel` should expose the properties of `SomeModel`

Comment: @dbkk: as long as you validate the data before sending it to the server, I don't see much issue with View seeing some Model parts.

Comment: @jberger Of course, there are multiple ways to skin the cat, but I was wondering what approach would be advisable from MVVM standpoint.

Comment: IMHO: Strengths of MVVM is decoupling View from Model to allow GUI and back-end design concurrently.  ViewModel merely _exposes_ Model to View via bindings.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class below that you can use for single threaded purposes.  I've only implemented Add and Remove, so you'd have to implement any other actions that you may use:...

Usage:

```
var viewModelWrapper = new ObservableCollectionViewModel<ItemViewModel, Model>(Model.List, item => new ItemViewModel(item));
```

Generic class - observable collection view model wrapper:

```
public class ObservableCollectionViewModel<TItemViewModel, TModel> :
    ObservableCollection<TItemViewModel>, IDisposable
    where TItemViewModel : BaseViewModel<TModel>
    where TModel : new()
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TModel> models;
    private readonly Func<TModel, TItemViewModel> viewModelConstructor;

    public ObservableCollectionViewModel(ObservableCollection<TModel> models,
        Func<TModel, TItemViewModel> viewModelConstructor)
    {
        this.models = models;
        this.viewModelConstructor = viewModelConstructor;
        CreateViewModelCollection();
        models.CollectionChanged += models_CollectionChanged;
        CollectionChanged += viewModels_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void viewModels_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        models.CollectionChanged -= models_CollectionChanged;
        try
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    {
                        foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
                        {
                            models.Add(((TItemViewModel)newItem).Model);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    {
                        foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
                        {
                            models.Remove(((TItemViewModel)oldItem).Model);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                // TODO: Add missing actions
                default: throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            models.CollectionChanged += models_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void models_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged -= viewModels_CollectionChanged;
        try
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    {
                        foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
                        {
                            Add(viewModelConstructor((TModel)newItem));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    {
                        var viewModels = this.Where(viewModel => e.OldItems.Contains(viewModel.Model)).ToList();
                        foreach (var viewModel in viewModels)
                        {
                            Remove(viewModel);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                // TODO: Add missing actions
                default: throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CollectionChanged += viewModels_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Only called once, by constructor
    /// </summary>
    private void CreateViewModelCollection()
    {
        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            Add(viewModelConstructor(model));
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        models.CollectionChanged -= models_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```